# Typesetting Greek letters in text mode: differences between alphabeta and textalpha

Tags: fonts, greek, alphabeta

This is a two-part question. First part is about the differences between `alphabeta`, and `textalpha`. Each package documentation says it typesets Greek letters in text mode.

So, are there any actual difference or pros/cons of using any one of them?

---

The second part is how to make the following MWE correctly produce all the commands set by both packages `textalpha` and `alphabeta`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={NoCommon, NoRare}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO]{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\begin{document}
    \section*{alphabeta} 
    \subsection*{small}
    \alpha  \beta  \gamma 
    \subsection*{capital}
    \Alpha \Beta \Gamma
    \section*{textalpha} 
    \subsection*{small}
    \textalpha \textbeta \textgamma
    \subsection*{capital}
    \textAlpha \textBeta \textGamma
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to work with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you need a main font with full coverage of Greek, which Latin Modern hasn't.

However, the package `alphabeta` has a few shortcomings. Here's a short excerpt:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\mathGamma\Gamma
  \let\mathDelta\Delta
  [...]
  \providecommand*{\Alpha}{\textAlpha}
  \providecommand*{\Beta}{\textBeta}
  [...]
}
```

What's the problem? The package does `\providecommand` and since at the point the instruction is executed, `\Alpha` has already been defined by `unicode-math`, so `\providecommand` does nothing.

You should *really* use `\text<letter>` or, of course, the actual letters.

My preference would go to `textalpha`, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO]{Latin Modern Math}

\usepackage{newcomputermodern} % this has Greek

\usepackage{alphabeta}

\begin{document}

αβγ

\textalpha  \textbeta  \textgamma 

ΑΒΓ

\textAlpha \textBeta \textGamma

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `"However, the package defines \Alpha to be the same as \textAlpha"` I am sorry but which package do you mean?

Comment: Also, I am confused a bit, you used the command `\textalpha` which is a part of `textalpha` package (I think), however, you loaded `alphabeta` package instead. So, does `alphabeta` automatically load `textalpha`? Do you mean that alphabeta and texalpha are two faces of the same coin? I can't really distinguish between them.

Comment: @Diaa No, `\textalpha` is not a property of the `textalpha` package. And `alphabeta` doesn't load the other package. They're two independent packages and I'd prefer `textalpha`.

Comment: My apologies, you said you prefer `\text<letter>` with `textalpha` package but I only see `alphabeta` loaded in your answer. **(1)** So, would you please show the approach you prefer with package `textalpha`? Also, **(2)** what package is the command `\textAlpha` in your answer part of? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Diaa OK, that's right: `\textAlpha` is provided by `textalpha`, which is *indeed* loaded by `alphabeta` (I overlooked this, sorry). However the latter does nothing really interesting, apart breaking something.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So, if I need to do it neatly, I should just replace `alphabeta` with `textalpha`. One final remark I asked in my question: `textalpha` provides the command `\textAlpha` and so does package `textcomp` (that is part of the tex source code), so how do I know this command is of which package?

Comment: @Diaa Where did you get the idea that `textcomp` defines `\textAlpha`? It doesn't.

Comment: I misunderstood some other statement. Thanks for the help.